# Saving the DOM as HTML after modification

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

In an Rails app I want to modify the DOM of a web page using javascript

Can I save the resulting HTML (of the whole page) after each modification to a database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With jQuery you could use `var html = $(document).html();`
Then post the html with `$.ajax()` to the controller where you choose to save it.

Comment: Thank you Keyo! (waiting a few minutes to award the answer)